# variant of coupon collector's problem - how many draws to cover p fraction of coupons

Tags: probability, statistics, coupon-collector

I have a urn with balls of "M" distinct colors. I draw "N" times (with replacement) from the urn. Probability of encountering each ball in a draw = $\frac{1}{M}$. How many expected draws (and the corresponding distribution of draws) do I need to be  I have drawn "p" fraction of the M colors ?

Comment: I've edited to include the distribution of draws / expected number of draws

Comment: Have you looked at the solution to the usual problem in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem)?  There is a sum that gets approximated by the natural log.  Instead of $M$ terms in the sum, you want the first $pM$ terms.  You can write the sum as (pM terms) +((1-p)M terms).  The second is  again like a logarithm, so you get the difference of two logs.

Answer (score 0):

When $k$ colours have been drawn, the expected number of draws required to draw the next undrawn colour is $\frac M{M-k}$. You want the sum of these expectations from $k=0$ to $k=\lceil pM\rceil-1$, which is

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{k=0}^{\lceil pM\rceil-1}\frac M{M-k}
&=&
M\left(\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}\frac1{M-k}-\sum_{\lceil pM\rceil}^{M-1}\frac1{M-k}\right)
\\
&=&
M\left(\sum_{j=1}^M\frac1j-\sum_{j=1}^{M-\lceil pM\rceil}\frac1j\right)
\\
&=&
M\left(H_M-H_{M-\lceil pM\rceil}\right)
\\
&\approx&
M\left(\gamma+\log M-\left(\gamma+\log\left(M-\lceil pM\rceil\right)\right)\right)
\\
&=&
M(\log M-\log(M-\lceil pM\rceil))
\\
&=&
-M\log\left(1-\frac{\lceil pM\rceil}M\right)
\\
&\approx&
-M\log\left(1-p\right)\;.
\end{eqnarray}

The approximations are not valid if $p$ is near $1$.